# Какой вид сказуемого?

Tags: сказуемые

Помогите разобраться со сказуемыми.
**Он делает прыжок**. Это простое глагольное "делает" или составное именное "делает прыжок" (=прыгает)?
**Они во всем находили удовольствие**. Аналогичный вопрос.
**Помоги выехать**. Сказуемое "помоги" или "помоги выехать"?
Неопределенная форма глагола (**чтобы идти домой**) - это простое глагольное сказуемое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Он ***делает прыжок*** (прыгает) – простое глагольное сказуемое.

Они во всем ***находили*** (что?) удовольствие – простое глагольное сказуемое и дополнение.

Из словаря: Найти 4. что. Получить, обрести. Н. применение. Н. сбыт. Н. в себе силы. Н. мужество.

***Помоги*** (кому-то: мне, ему) выехать – простое глагольное сказуемое и объектный инфинитив, сравнить: я ***могу выехать*** (составное глагольное сказуемое, модальная связка и инфинитив).

Чтобы ***идти***  (куда?) домой –  сказуемое, выраженное независимым инфинитивом (без связки).

Comment: Спасибо большое. Всё понятно, кроме последнего. Так всё-таки какое это сказуемое с инфинитивом? Простое глагольное?

Comment: Его можно назвать глагольным сказуемым с отсутствующей связкой.  В некоторых случаях (значение невозможности действия) связка возможна, например: Здесь не проехать. Вчера здесь было не проехать. А простое глагольное сказуемое обычно выражается спрягаемой формой глагола.